# сортировка ключей массива с изменением значений

Tags: php

Есть массив символов с ключами, например:

```
<?php
$key='привет';
for ($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($key);$i++)
{
    $k[$i]=mb_substr($key,$i,1);
}
?>
```

В результате каждый символ будет иметь свой ключ:

```
0 => п;
1 => р;
2 => и;
3 => в;
4 => е;
5 => т;
```

Как отсортировать массив таким образом, чтобы ключи встали в алфавитном порядке, а значения остались на своих местах, т.е.:

```
3 => п;
4 => р;
2 => и;
0 => в;
1 => е;
5 => т;
```

Comment: вы смотрели перечень функций для сортировки массивов в пхп?

Comment: Можно узнать что должно быть в случае "здравствуй", интересует как должны работать повторяющиеся буквы.

Comment: @teran да, смотрел

Comment: @Arnial они должны просто идти по порядку, повторяясь, т.е. 0=>в; 1=>в; и т.д.

Comment: и не нашли там [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php)?

Comment: @teran а разве uasort() подойдёт? ТС же нужна переиндексация массива, а uasort() вроде бы сохраняет связь между ключами и значениями?

Comment: @Эдуард а, действительно, туплю.

Comment: @teran я думаю, что стандартными ф-ями для сортировки такое не реализовать, и нужно писать что-то своё.

Answer (score 4):

вероятность повтора букв в исходном слове несколько усложняет решение, иначе можно было бы обойтись парой флипов (`array_flip`).

В общем вот наши исходные (добивил `т`):

```
$key = "приветт";
$values = preg_split("//u", $key, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

1. Сортируем данные (тут без учета кривости сортировки с буквой `ё`).
2. В массиве `$map` запоминаем индексы с учетом повтором букв, например, `map['т']` будет содержать `[5,6]`
3. собираем искомый массив `$result`

--

```
$data = $values;
sort($data);

$map = [] ;
array_walk($data, function($l, $idx) use (&$map){ $map[$l][] = $idx; });

$result =  [];
array_walk($values, function($l) use (&$map, &$result){ 
                        $result[ array_shift($map[$l]) ] = $l; 
                    });
```

результт

```
[3] => п 
[4] => р 
[2] => и 
[0] => в 
[1] => е 
[5] => т 
[6] => т
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вот такое решение в лоб...

```
$key='здравствуй';
$k = [];
for ($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($key);$i++)
{
    $k[$i]=mb_substr($key,$i,1);
}
$saved = $k; // сохраняем копию исходного массива
sort($k);   // сортируем по значению
$result = [];
foreach ($saved as $letter) { // по порядку для каждой буквы
    $index = array_search($letter, $k);// находим индекс(из-за этого O(N^2), флипнуть тут нельзя, потеряем индексы повторяющихся букв..)
    $result[$index] = $letter;
    unset($k[$index]); // удаляем использованные индексы
}
;
var_dump($result);
```

O(nlogn) вариант:

```
$map = $res = [];
$saved = $k;
sort($k);

foreach ($k as $i => $l) $map[$l][] = $i;
foreach ($saved as $l) $res[array_shift($map[$l])] = $l;

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: с циклами понятнее  чем с `array_walk` выглядит :)

Comment: @teran, это всё из-за `use`

Comment: были бы лямбды, было бы красиво :)

Comment: Похоже, в ближайшем будущем не будет лямбд(стрелочных). Уже драфта 3 отклонили..

Comment: @teran, а в php7 циклы всё еще быстрее, чем array_walk?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский честно сказать, я об этом особо не задумывался никогда, но `foreach` и `walk` что раньше что сейчас особо и не отличались вроде. По крайней мере на фоне полезной работы в цикле это будет все менее и менее заметно.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!